# Create a dictionary from a tuple with a similar key

Tags: python

Suppose I have these tuples:

```
('eggs', 20, 30)
('eggs', 40, 23)
('eggs', 10, 24)
('apple', 2, 22)
('apple', 42, 3)
```

I want a dictionary to look like this:

```
{
eggs: [[20, 30], [40,23], [10,24]], 
apple: [[2,22], [42,3]]
}
```

How would I get this

I tried doing this:

```
dic = {}
for d in data:
   dic[d[0]] += [[d[1], d[2]]

#d[0] being eggs or apple, d[1] and d[2] being the numbers
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is correct if you use `defaultdict`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

dic = defaultdict(list)

for d in datas:
   dic[d[0]] += [[d[1], d[2]]]

print (dic)

#defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'eggs': [[20, 30], [40, 23], [10, 24]], 'apple': [[2, 22], [42, 3]]})
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
>>> t = [('eggs', 20, 30), ('eggs', 40, 23), ('eggs', 10, 24), ('apple', 2, 22), ('apple', 42, 3)]

>>> d = {}        
>>> for k, v1, v2 in t:
    d.setdefault(k,[]).append([v1,v2])
```

---

**Output:**

```
>>> d             
{'eggs': [[20, 30], [40, 23], [10, 24]], 'apple': [[2, 22], [42, 3]]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @shaikmoeed's answer, but with iterator unpacking:

```
dic = {}
for key, *values in lst:
    dic.setdefault(key, []).append(values)
```

so that given:

```
lst = [
    ('eggs', 20, 30),
    ('eggs', 40, 23),
    ('eggs', 10, 24),
    ('apple', 2, 22),
    ('apple', 42, 3)
]
```

`dic` becomes:

```
{'eggs': [[20, 30], [40, 23], [10, 24]], 'apple': [[2, 22], [42, 3]]}
```